# deserializing System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Tags: c#

My API responds with with JSON as a string, when my Unity app receives this object, I'm unsure how to deserialize it into an object from it's type of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, I want to make it an object of my class: `PlayerInfo` which is serializable.

```
void OnPlayerLocalUpdate(Socket socket, Packet packet, params object[] args)
{
  var myObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(args[0].ToString());

}
```

The above code raises:

```
JSON parse error: Invalid value.   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJsonInternal(string,object,System.Type) at UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson (System.String json, System.Type type)
```

How do I deserialize that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void OnPlayerLocalUpdate(Socket socket, Packet packet, params object[] args)
{
  var serialized = JsonUtility.ToJson(args[0]);
  var myObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(serialized);
}
```

First you need to serialize it then you deserialize it your expected object type. If args[0] is a Dictionary it should serialize to valid json object. Another way of achieving this is to initialize your PlayerInfo manually. Then use reflection to set its' properties.